# Bootstrap columns of different height not fitting in vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am outputting a grid of boxes from database and formatting with bootstrap.  Each box is col-4 so there are 3 per row.

My code looks kinda like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">contentbox code here</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">contentbox code here</div>  
  <div class="col-md-4">contentbox code here</div>  
  <div class="col-md-4">contentbox code here</div>
  // etc....
</div>
```

The problem is that when boxes are different heights it will push the below box onto a new line and leave an ugly gaps like so:

[image]

I've gone through the bootstrap documentation and I can't figure out how to fix this.  I have tried adding clearfix into the loop and setting `display: inline` but cant get it fit together without the gap.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

I looked at other solutions on here and they had 3 fixed columns.  That won't work as I am outputting from database so I don't know the heights of boxes so if I split them between 3 fixed columns somehow then one could be a lot taller than the others and look bad.

I have seen sites that fit together nicely but not sure how it is done.

Comment: They are generated trough PHP right? So yes, generate them into different rows with every row containing 4 col-md-4 items.

Comment: I want to make the columns move up into gap. creating another row will be putting container so they cant move up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question, there's an existing solution that would fit for your needs however it does require a little bit of extra JavaScript coding.

[Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

> Masonry is a JavaScript grid layout library. It works by placing
>   elements in optimal position based on available vertical space, sort
>   of like a mason fitting stones in a wall. You’ve probably seen it in
>   use all over the Internet.

Comment: I used isotope.js, it was easy to implement this :)

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap native classes col-md-* are originally floated

so try to set `float:none` on the columns

Comment: That makes them all go into a single column down the left hand side of the page

Answer (score 0):

You can build the rows programmatically if you'd like.

For example, in PHP:

```
$posts = ["Post 1","Post 2","Post 3","Post 4","Post 5"]; // Your posts
$post_number = 1; // Counter

foreach($posts as $post){

    // Open a new row if the first column
    if($post_number % 3 == 1)
        echo "<div class='row'>\n";

    // Post content goes here
    echo "<div class='col-md-4'> Post Content: ".$post." </div>";

    // Close the row if the last column
    if($post_number % 3 == 0)
        echo "</div>";

   // Move to next post
   $post_number++;

}

// Close the row if there's not already a closing tag
if(count($posts) % 3 != 0)
    echo "</div>";
```

Outputs:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-4'> Post Content: Post 1 </div>
    <div class='col-md-4'> Post Content: Post 2 </div>
    <div class='col-md-4'> Post Content: Post 3 </div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-4'> Post Content: Post 4 </div>
    <div class='col-md-4'> Post Content: Post 5 </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

Whoops! Just saw your reply to your original post... my solution will not work if you want the posts to move up to fill the gap.